# Getting error with dll while importing ctypes in python

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes

I am using Python 2.5.2 on Windows XP and I am trying to use ctypes in a python script by importing it (import ctypes). Now I am getting following error:

```
File "C:\Python25\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

In **init**.py, Class CDLL has the line 348, and I am not sure that if the DLL is missing because I am using the same script at another computer where it works perfectly.

I have already declared an Environment Variable, **PYTHONPATH**, containing all the addresses of Python Installation Directory.

Could you please guide me here to resolve the issue.

Comment: The error means Windows can't find the DLL or one of its dependencies, not a Python module. Update your question with information about the DLL you're trying to load and the relevant section of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will update it asap.

Comment: You didn't add the DLL(s) and their location relative to your script or show the CDLL call itself. Anyway, Windows will search the executable's directory (where python.exe is located), the current directory, and directories in the process `PATH` (not Python's `sys.path`). You can modify the latter at runtime. For example: `os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + r'DriveLetter:\Path\To\Your\DLL'`.